# one div showing and one div not showing

Tags: html, positioning

I'm trying to do something really simple.  Two divs, one on top of the other, top one red border, bottom one blue border, I have no idea why the top one doesn't show.

http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/

this should be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have them positioned as absolute. Change it to relative.

`position:relative;`

Also, I suggest not doing inline styling. Create a css file or put the css on top.

Here is your example updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/1/

reduced further:

http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/2/

Comment: one more question, I wanted to put in in this page here, updated, why isn't that container div surrounding? it just sits on top of them even though it should contain.  http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/layers2.html

Comment: @loriensleafs reduced the html down some more, you can see it's much easier to read when content and style are separate.

Comment: @loriensleafs unfortunately I can't get to your website where I am at. It's blocked for me. Maybe someone else can check it out and help you out.

Comment: last question, how do I get that green layer to be on top of the those first two colored layers?  http://jsfiddle.net/2TAaC/3/